# Query array vs. Active Record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I call  something like `all` on this? I would like to call the `check_other_notification` method on all the notifications that query return.

Could someone suggest a good description on this Active Relation vs array topic? I read about it in many different places but I'm still a bit confused.

```
Notification
  .between_other_recipient(current_user, @user)
  .last
  .check_other_notification
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want to call a `check_other_notification` method on each object, returned by the query.

If so, use [`find_each`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each) for this:

```
Notification
  .between_other_recipient(current_user, @user)
  .find_each do |notification|
    notification.check_other_notification
end
```

`find_each` if very efficient method, since it process objects in batches (by default the batch size is 1000 records, but you can specify any other amount).

In your case `each` would work, since I do not think there are hundreds of thousands of notifications, but if so - `find_each` is a perfect match.

---

## Edit

Difference between `collect` and `find_each`.

Quoting docs on `find_each`:

> `find_each` is only intended to use for batch processing of large
>   amounts of records that wouldn’t fit in memory all at once. If you
>   just need to loop over less than 1000 records, it’s probably better
>   just to use the regular find methods.

If you use `collect` (`map`), which is a method from Array class - it would first load the whole collection of records into the memory before processing. This can eat to much memory and lead to problems, when the collection is big.

Important point is: **do not use Ruby to process database stuff**, when it is possible to use ORM (when not, SQL will do).

[Here is a short article](http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/553/Rails-Tips-for-Speeding-up-ActiveRecord-Queries#.VmZ8sCCrSfY) showing few examples of using Array's vs AR's methods, and also describing few other things to be aware of when querying AR collection.

Comment: Andrey, yes I'd like to call it on each object. So I should use this in the controller, right? One more question. I read about the collect method which does something similar. Can you tell me the difference between the find_each and collect in simple terms?

Comment: Andrey, could you tell me a "to-avoid" example (if it's possible on the code above) when sby calls ruby instead of SQL/active record? Besides that do you know a good resource where I can read some comparison about these (ruby vs active record vs sql). It's hard to make mental picture when to use which one if you read separated resources on each one.

Comment: Example of using Ruby in this example is this: `Notification.between_other_recipient (..).all.map(&:check_other_notification)` - the whole collection is loaded into memory before it starts to actually calling a method on each object. I'm using phone now, so can't really surf the net - if I find good article tomorrow morning - I'll update the answer and notify you

Comment: I just wanted to chime in re: `each` vs `map` vs `reduce`. They will all iterate through an enumerable / array, but are useful for different things:

- each will just go through each item and run whatever code you specify. it returns the original enumerable

- map will return a new array, having transformed each item according to the function

- reduce / inject will return one value

Comment: @SzilardMagyar did not find a lot info containing what you've requested, but i've updated the answer with a link to an article showing some things to know. Good luck learning. PS. Always read documentation, ain't nobody says it better, than docs.